# wsdl to asmx webservice HELP!

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I've searched for this problem and I always get stuck on the step after you've generated a .cs file using the command "wsdl.exe myfile.wsdl /l:CS /ServerInterface" in the Microsoft Visual Studio prompt. I've imported the .cs file into a Visual Studio web service project. and It have a service1.asmx.cs file I dont know what to do with.

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to .NET, C#, Visual Studio and Web Service so a step to step guide would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Forgo the command-line wsdl.exe utility - it's much easier in Visual Studio itself.  If you're using VS 2008 or later, right-click on your project, select Add Service Reference and point it to the WSDL on the server you'll be connecting to (e.g. http://www.blahblah.com/service.asmx?WSDL) and it will generate the proxy classes and connection parameters in an app.config file.</strike>

From where you are, instantiate an object of the proxy class it generated (make sure the namespace it generated is included with a `using` statement) and make sure it is bound to an endpoint:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding =
    new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
EndpointAddress address =
    new EndpointAddress("http://webservices.blahblah.com/service.asmx");
MyService service = new MyServiceClient(binding, address);
```

and then invoke the remote methods on it:

```
try
{
    service.DoSomething("someParameter");
    if (service.GetSomeStatus())
    {
    }
}
finally
{
    (service as IDisposable).Dispose();
}
```

<strike>For VS 2005 or earlier, use Add Web Reference and the rest of the procedure is similar.</strike>

Comment: Thank you for the awnser, but I can't do it in this way because I dont have the URL to where im going to connect my web service.

Comment: Gotcha.  Then rewind somewhat and let me rephrase.  Consider using `svcutil.exe` over `wsdl.exe`, but that will be what you need to use, only having a file with WSDL in it.  The problem at this point will be that you can't execute the web service without knowing your endpoint (URL) connection at some level.  How are you expecting the service call to execute?

Comment: Isnt it possible to create public web services where anyone can connect to it? Then its impossible to know the endpoints URL? Maybe I forgot to tell you that I'm the server that's going to recieve calls and not the client.

Comment: On that note, you're not needing to generate a client proxy with svcutil or wsdl - that's up to the people calling your web service.  Once you write your service and publish it somewhere (you need to put it on a server somewhere, there's not just a public place for web services to be dropped, AFAIK), your users will know that somewhere and connect to it.